# Wordpress image stretch on home page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image which I'd like to display in the full width of my browser, just below the header of my site, as can be seen at the site www.priverevaux.com

How can i do this? I am able to add the image to the page, however it doesn't stretch to full screen even when i set the width of the image to 100%. 
I think it's sitting inside a container which doesn't allow it to stretch further than the page content area. 
I've tried changing the background image of the page itself, however the image doesn't sit directly under the header.

Thanks

Comment: use it as a background image, but set a margin the same size as your header ? or if your header disapear when you scroll down, set your background-image on your main content div

Comment: @Neil how can I edit the main content div? When I set its as a background image it places the image halfway down the content area of the page.

Comment: thats normal, that's the basic behaviour of background-image, you need to set some options you can find on any backgroun-image doc. If then you can't achieve your goal, just create a snippet and show us what you've tried ;)

Comment: 1)Set background-image:url and background-size:cover for full width.
2)Set position:Absolute of header and make main div as margin-top:0 for second case

Comment: it's never written that his header must be absolute, and then it will be false as the background image will be centered with cover, and the main div will be behind the header...

Comment: Please include the code you tried already and we see why it didn't work and help you to change it.